# Can I generate a transaction on the server and send it to the client for payment

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, metamask

I have built a smart contract method to which I pass some sensitive data that needs to be stored on the blockchain and alter the state of the contract. I, the creator of the contract don't want to be the one paying for the fees of that transaction. I want the user on the browser to approve and pay for it.

However, I do not want to generate the transaction object on the browser as I want some of the data that will be passed to the contract to be hidden from the client. If I understand the web3 syntax correctly, in the code below, I'm doing just that

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
   from: walletAddressOfTheUserThatWillPayForTheTransaction,
   data: myContract.methods.changeState(..sensitive data...).encodeABI()
})
```

However I do not want the above to happen on the browser. In my head, the sequence of events should look like this (***pseudocode***):

```
// server
let transactionObject = {
   from: walletAddressOfTheUserThatWillPayForTheTransaction,
   data: myContract.methods.changeState(..sensitive data...).encodeABI()
}

sendToClient(encrypt(transactionObject)) 


// client
let encryptedTransactionObject = await fetchEncryptedTransactionObjectFromServer()

// this should open up Metamask for the user so that they may approve and finalise the transaction on the browser
web3.eth.sendTransaction(encryptedTransactionObject)
```

Is this possible ? Is there some other way of achieving this? Could you provide me with some hints about the actual syntax to be used?

Comment: When calling the ```sendTransaction``` method, the data of the transaction is already encrypted, but that's not to say that someone couldn't figure it out.  I would advise having the client sign a message that is also passed along with that information and then verified on chain.  This way someone trying to read that data would need both the sensitive data and also the signature which would be very hard to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I do not want to generate the transaction object on the browser as I want some of the data that will be passed to the contract to be hidden from the client.

Then you should not be using public blockchains in the first place, as all data on public blockchains, by definition, is public. Anyone can read it.

Comment: If I'm using a custom contract, I can restrict access to its methods to specific callers based on private keys for examples, that only the caller and the contract itself will know.

Comment: And I thought that with public access you have access to transactions, not internal states of contracts

Comment: All data is public, including any internal state of the contract, because otherwise how would the blockchain nodes be able to execute the transactions.

Comment: So the idea of deploying a smart-contract onto an existing blockchain such as Ethereum, is totally unsafe since the internal state and data stored in a smart-contract will be available for anyone to use, so if I wanted privacy, I would have to build my own blockchain ?

Comment: The trick is not to store confidental data on a blockchain. The public blockchains are transferring billions of dollars value everyday, totally safe. I suggest you study or take a basic courses on blockchain architecture before attempting to develop an application on it, so you understand better how blockchains work. StackOverflow is not the right forum to do tutorials.

Comment: I see. Because blockchains are "totally safe" I was also under the impression that only the owner/creator of a contract can have access to some parts of their internal state, and that the nodes of the blockchain are only meant to call methods of a contract without knowledge of what those methods are doing or what values are manipulating. My question was quite specific. It was whether what I describe in the OP is possible or not. Apparently it's not and that's good enough of an answer.

Comment: This article is actually very enlightening: https://medium.com/@mikesmolenski/smart-contracts-privacy-vs-confidentiality-645b6e9c6e5a I will look more into that.